# Wordpress custom query missing two posts

Tags: wordpress, pagination

I am running a custom query but when returning posts_per_page, it is always two behind. I am using a custom post type called events, that is pulling in the code to display the posts from the functions file. I also want to implement pagination(not working also), will this be a problem?

I have ran var dump which returns everything in the query including posts before the current date. I imagine because it's dumping before the if statement? Any ideas?

Any ideas?

```
<?php
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    //Current exhibitions
    $args = array(
           'post_type' => 'exhibitions',
           'orderby'   => 'exhibition_start_date',
           'meta_key'  => 'exhibition_start_date',
           'order'     => 'ASC',
           'posts_per_page' => 6,
           'paged' => $paged
       );

        $my_query = new WP_Query( $args );

      while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post();
           $exhibition_start_date = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'exhibition_start_date', true);
           //Current

           if ($exhibition_start_date >= date('Y-m-d') ) {
               get_exhibition_container();
           }

        endwhile;

   wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

New code: (I've also added in my initial loop which brings in the page content, thought it could interfear?)

```
<div role="main" class="clearfix">  
    <div class="one-column">
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php endwhile; else: ?>
     <?php endif; ?>

<?php
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    //Current exhibitions
    $args = array(
           'post_type' => 'exhibitions',
           'meta_query' => array(
           array (
                    'key' => 'exhibition_start_date',
                    'value' => date('Y-m-d'),
                    'compare' => '>='
                 )
            ),
           'orderby'   => 'exhibition_start_date',
           'meta_key'  => 'exhibition_start_date',
           'order'     => 'ASC',
           'posts_per_page' => 10,
           'paged' => $paged
       );

        $my_query = new WP_Query( $args );


      while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post();
           $exhibition_start_date = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'exhibition_start_date', true);
           //Current
            get_exhibition_container();


        endwhile;

   wp_reset_postdata();
?>

<div class="previous-holder">
<?php previous_posts_link(); ?>
</div>
<div class="next-holder">
<?php next_posts_link(); ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a `if` condition in your loop, you should use `meta_query` param :

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'exhibitions',

    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'exhibition_start_date',
            'value' => date('Y-m-d'),
            'compare' => '>='
        )
    ),

    'orderby'   => 'exhibition_start_date',
    'meta_key'  => 'exhibition_start_date',
    'order'     => 'ASC',

    'posts_per_page' => 6,
    'paged' => $paged
);
```

**EDIT** : About pagination

[`previous_posts_link` codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/previous_posts_link) :

> Prints a link to the previous set of posts within the **current** query.

You should try using `previous_posts_link()` and `next_posts_link()` before `wp_reset_postdata()`

Comment: Thankyou you are a genius, the only problem is now pagination still isn't working?

Comment: At the bottom outside of the loop, do I need to reference them inside?

Comment: Not inside. Please add the corresponding code to your question

Comment: Thanks, I've added this 'echo '<div class="previous-holder">' . previous_posts_link() . '
</div><div class="next-holder">' . next_posts_link() . '</div>';

wp_reset_postdata(); ?>' - but the pagination links are still not showing

Comment: nevermind figured it out, wordpress pagination only works if the query is called wp_query